# Duplicate obs to fit other obs in df - R

Tags: r

In the below image you can see that there are 12 teams objects and 6 time objects. When I add this variable into the Dataframe it obviously does not fit and errors out. Is there a way to duplicate the time so it shows up twice, 1 for the top name and 1 for the bottom in the same matchup?

[image]

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tm)
library(stringi)
library(readr)


today <- Sys.Date()#+1
today <- gsub("-", "", today, fixed=TRUE)

url <- read_html(paste0('https://classic.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nhl-hockey/?date=', as.character(today)))

gametime <- url %>%
  html_nodes('.eventLine-time .eventLine-book-value') %>%
  html_text()

teams <- url %>%
  html_nodes('.team-name a') %>%
  html_text()

roster <- data.frame(gametime = time, TEAM = teams)
```

ADDING IN EDIT: gametime = rep(gametime, each=2)

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tm)
library(stringi)
library(readr)


today <- Sys.Date()#+1
today <- gsub("-", "", today, fixed=TRUE)

url <- read_html(paste0('https://classic.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nhl-hockey/?date=', as.character(today)))

gametime <- url %>%
  html_nodes('.eventLine-time .eventLine-book-value') %>%
  html_text()

gametime = rep(gametime, each=2)

teams <- url %>%
  html_nodes('.team-name a') %>%
  html_text()

roster <- data.frame(gametime = time, TEAM = teams)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rep(gametime, each=2)` will duplicate each element of `gametime`.

Comment: Would I have to Merge that into the all ready existing dataframe? I am getting an error if I just write gametime <- rep(gametime, each=2) below the gametime scrape.

Comment: Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame.  That happens when I try to add gametime to DF

Comment: You are using `time` to create your dataframe, not `gametime`.